# Topics from theoretical computer science suitable for a bachelor thesis?

Tags: project-topic

this is my first question, so please be patient :) My question in particular:
Is the field of theoretical computer science so complex, that it is just "too much" for a bachelor thesis? Unfortunately I haven't found any old thesises because the relevant chair of the university hasn't been occupied for years.

Because of theoretical computer science is the only topic that really interests me, I thought of writing my bachelor thesis in this field.
What would be suitable topics or at least fields that can be arranged in the limited focus of a bachelor thesis?
I thought of topics like parametrized complexity or formal software verfication (which is actually a bit of the target)

Best regards

Comment: Certainly not. Plenty of problems in the theory of programming languages is not too complex, for example!

Comment: Many students write a bachelor thesis in theoretical computer science. There are always some questions which are open but not too hard. As a researcher in the area, I would say Parameterized Complexity is a good research topic for interested bachelor students since there is some freedom in picking the questions to look at. I would recommend, however, that you choose a topic for which you have an advisor that has some experience in this particular field, preferably from your university.